# Telnet and Firewall

Tags: networking, firewall

I would like to transfer file from one machine to another using telnet. When I tried to connect the two computers by telnet, using the same network, the file was sent correctly and everything was fine. However, when I tried to change the network the connection was failed. How can I allow a firewall to accept connection from different networks?

Comment: 1. ditch telnet, use ssh or scp or sftp. security wise a better method 2. changing the network... HOW? is most important here since that is needed for an answer. 3. firewall does not normally block transfers inbetween local network. Seems to me more related to not correctly changing your network :) Please edit into the question a bit more details.

Comment: You'll also need to add some more information. What are you using for a firewall? What are the IP address formats of your networks? What did you change, specifically, from when it worked to when it didn't?

Comment: in Machine A I used this command to send the file to machine B (./listen.pl 2000 File.rtf) In Machine B I used this command (telnet IP number 2000) if I connected these 2 machines to the same network the file was send and everything was fine. However, I would like to connect them using different networks how can I allow the firewall of ubuntu OS to accept the connection from different network

Answer (score 0):

Use `iptables -A INPUT --dport [telnetport] -j ACCEPT`.

Comment: That'll accept the port, but will it solve the different network issue?

Comment: Well, it allows any traffic to the given port; the network does not matter. So yes it will solve it, if the problem is connected to a specific network.

Comment: in Machine A I used this command to send the file to machine B (./listen.pl 2000 File.rtf) In Machine B I used this command (telnet IP number 2000) if I connected these 2 machines to the same network the file was send and everything was fine. However, I would like to connect them using different networks how can I allow the firewall of ubuntu OS to accept the connection from different network